# Final theorem of arithmetic

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

I have been trying to prove the "Final theorem of arithmetic" that says  $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are the only conmutative fields, $\mathbb{R}$-vectorial spaces with finite dimension.
It´s easy to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ meet the conditions, but I dont know how can I prove that they are the only ones, any idea?

Comment: Maybe that this is the theorem that you are searching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $[K:L]$ is finite, then $K$ is an algebraic extension of $L$.  $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically-closed...

Comment: It is a good hint.  Some details remain to fill in for a complete proof.